# Find the coefficient of $x^2y^2z^4$ in the expansion of $(x-2y+z)^8$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I need help solving this question​. How do I start?

**Attempt at solution**
*The term that contains $x^2y^2z^4$ is ${8 \choose 4} (-2y)^2(z)$ ?
*

Comment: You start with the multinomial theorem, which tells you how to expand multinomial powers. Do you know this theorem?

Comment: No I am not familiar with this therorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 3):

The multinomial theorem will tell you the following (I'll state it for trinomials)
$$
(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^n = \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = n} \binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3} \prod_{i=1}^3 x_i^{k_i}
$$

In our case, we have $x_1 = x$, $x_2 = -2y$, $x_3 =z$. So if  we are finding  the coefficient of $x^2 y^2 z^4$, note that this is equivalent to $x_1^2\times \frac{x_2^2}{4} \times x_3^4$, which means we have to take $k_1 = 2,k_2 = 2, k_3 = 4$. This gives us the answer $\binom{8}{2,4,4} \times 4$ (which comes because $y^2 = \frac{x_2^2}{4}$, so we have to account for this):
$$
\frac{8! \times 4}{ 4! \times 2!\times 2!} = 1680
$$
which should be correct (and is , I checked on Wolfram Alpha to make sure).

I case you are not aware of this theorem, read it up on Wikipedia. The proof is similar to that of the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 3):

We  can also iteratively apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)* in order to find the coefficients. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^2y^2z^4](x-2y+z)^8&=[x^2y^2z^4]\sum_{j=0}^8\binom{8}{j}x^j(-2y+z)^{8-j}\tag{1}\\
> &=[y^2z^4]\binom{8}{2}(-2y+z)^6\\
> &=\binom{8}{2}[y^2z^4]\sum_{j=0}^6\binom{6}{j}(-2y)^jz^{6-j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}(-2)^2\\
> &=1680
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial theorem and select the coefficient of $x^2$.
- In (2) we again apply the binomial theorem and select the coefficient  of $y^2z^4$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\bracks{x^{2}y^{2}z^{4}}\pars{x - 2y + z}^{8} & =
\bracks{x^{2}y^{2}z^{4}}\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{b = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{c = 0}^{\infty}{8! \over a!\,b!\,c!}\bracks{a + b + c = 8}x^{a}\pars{-2y}^{b}z^{c}
\\[5mm] & = {8! \over 2!\,2!\,4!}\pars{-2}^{2} = 8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 =
\bbx{\ds{1680}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  if you expand $(x-2y+z)^2$, every term has total degree $2$.

Answer (score 0):

First we need the coefficient of $x^2$ in $$\{x+(z-2y)\}^8$$ which is $$\binom86(z-2y)^6$$

Now what is the coefficient of $z^4$ in $$(z-2y)^6?$$

Comment: 8 choose 2? Why did you write it as {x+(z-2y)^8}?

Comment: @Philip, $$\binom nr=\binom n{n-r}$$ I wanted to use   binomial expansion.