# Multinomial theorem problem

Tags: combinatorics

I am supposed to determine the coefficient of $$x^{2}z^{3}$$ of expression:$$(x+y+z)^{5}$$. What I did:
$$\sum _{i=0}^{5}\binom{5}{i}x^{5-i}\left ( y+z \right )^{i}=\sum _{i=0}^{5}\binom{5}{i}x^{5-i}\sum _{j=0}^{i}\binom{i}{j}y^{i-j}z^{j}$$ and that should be equal to$$\binom{5}{i,j,5-i-j}x^{i}y^{j}z^{5-i-j}$$ Can anyone please explain the last step?

Comment: There are really many duplicates (or almost duplicates) here of this question, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484908/find-the-coefficient-of-w3x5z2-in-the-expansion-of-wxyz10), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258535/find-the-coefficient-of-x2y2z4-in-the-expansion-of-x-2yz8), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418955/find-the-coefficient-of-x15y4-in-the-expansion-of-2x-3y19?rq=1), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\require{cancel} \dbinom{5}{i}\dbinom{i}{j} = \dfrac{5!}{(5-i)!\cancel{i!}}\cdot \dfrac{\cancel{i!}}{j!(i-j)!} = \dfrac{5!}{(5-i)!j!(i-j)!}$$

Now, we re-index:

$$i' = i-j, j'=j$$

This implies $i = i'+j'$, so the RHS of the equation above becomes:

$$\dfrac{5!}{(5-i'-j')!j'!i'!} = \dbinom{5}{i',j',5-i'-j'}$$

Comment: Thank you so much